# How to create interceptor for default repository methods in loopback4?

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

When I try to access default repository code I want to control some values before executing the default crud function in repository. How to I achive that?

ex:

```
...
@repository.getter('PersonRepository') private personRepositoryGetter: Getter<PersonRepository>
...

...
someEndpoint(){
    const personRepository = await this.personRepositoryGetter();
    const createdPerson = await personRepository.create(someData)
}
...
```

In `personRepository.create()` I want to write intercept. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Is there any specific issue with following [the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Interceptor.html), or simply overriding the methods and calling `super`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi see **Access to data before writing to the databases** in:

[https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/LB3-vs-LB4-request-response-cycle.html#access-to-data-before-writing-to-the-databases"](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/LB3-vs-LB4-request-response-cycle.html#access-to-data-before-writing-to-the-databases%22)